# how to access bytecode of some file/function in android

Tags: android

I want to access bytecode of some file/function from dex file in Android. Please suggest me the suitable way.
 Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to do?  Have you investigated any particular APIs for doing this?  Do you have some sample code?

Comment: I am trying to access dex file using code :-                         DexFile df = new DexFile("classes.dex");
       Class cl = df.loadClass("HelloAndroid", res);    But I am getting error that unable to open dex file.

Answer (score 0):

first you need a tool called dex2jar,. it will translate dex to jar file. then you can use jd-gui, the source code is quite readable as dex2jar makes some optimizations.